# Trycatch skipping errors/warnings

Tags: r, debugging, try-catch

I am trying to understand how to use tryCatch() in a loop, where it would skip any values that create an error and move to the next item in the loop. To understand the syntax I created a quick loop with logs as follows:

```
i=0
Log<- function(x) {
tryCatch(log(x),
 warning = function(w) {i=i+1;next},
            error = function(e) {i=i+1;next},
                   finally={log(x)}) 
 }

 for(input in (-5:5)) {
   print(paste("log of", input, "=", Log(input)))
 }
```

I am trying to skip any value of log that produces a warning or message (so from -5 to 0 in this case) and take a tally of it (thus the i=0 at first andd the i=i+1). However this is not working, it generates the following error:

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : no loop for break/next, jumping to top level
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem with your original code.  You are calling `next` inside the `tryCatch` and it is not needed/makes no sense.  This is why the error message says there is no loop to break from, because your code is not inside a loop when `next` is being called.  Instead, just increment your counter on warning or error and let the next call to `Log()` happen from outside the function.  Try this code:

```
Log <- function(x) {
    tryCatch(log(x),
             warning = function(w) {i=i+1},
             error = function(e) {i=i+1},
             finally = {log(x)}) 
}
```

But why are you calling `log(x)` again in the `finally` block?  Instead, you might be able to just omit it entirely.

Comment: Typo my bad, just tried it and still getting the same error message